# How to redirect / path into /app in react router 6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-component

I have different routes for different pages.

```
<Routes>
<Route path="/"/>
<Route path='/app' element={home}/>
</Routes>
```

How to redirect / into /app in the new version of react router?

Answer (score 1):

you can do as shown below

```
<Routes>
  <Route exact path="/app" element={<home />} />
  <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" />} />
</Routes>
```